# How to set custom user view mode for comments

Tags: theming, 8

How do I control which view mode of a user account appears on different pages?

I have a Compact user view mode with two fields I want to appear in forum posts and comments. I then have a more complete user view mode I would like to have appear on the users home page and eventually i would like a different view mode for article bylines.

I cannot, for the life of me though, figure out how to actually have any of these display.

I want to modify the layout of user.html.twig for the user home pages to have additional headings and information. But then it gets used wherever the user entity appears. Am I suppose to create specific twig templates for every user appearance or is there some more sensible way to control the fields that appear?

I tried accessing specific user entity fields and styling them in templates such as `node--forum.html.twig` but I can only seem to access the complete user entity with `{{ author_picture }}` - why is it named that if it is the entire entity? or the user name with `{{ author_name }}`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `{{ author_picture }}` and `{{ author_name }}` are prepared in preprocess in the hook [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.2.x). You can modify these variables or add your own in a custom preprocess hook.

Or you can make the field `uid` configurable in UI by modifying the field definition in the node entity:

**mymodule.module**

```
function mymodule_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node') {
    if (isset($fields['uid'])) {
      $fields['uid']->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
    }
  }
}
```

and you'll find the *Authored by* field in the *Manage Display* page, where you can configure how the referenced user entity is formatted (which view mode is used).

A third and IMHO perferable option is to use the module [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).